# Remove ROS artifact from CMake install

Tags: ros-kinetic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using CPack to create .deb binaries. The relevant part of the CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
INSTALL(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}_node  DESTINATION bin)
INSTALL(FILES doc/${PROJECT_NAME}.yaml DESTINATION share)
INSTALL(FILES doc/${PROJECT_NAME}.service DESTINATION lib/systemd/system)

SET(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER "Maintainer")
SET(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
```

The .deb file gets build fine, the only problem i have is that ROS is adding som files:

- .catkin
- local/.rosinstall
- local/env.sh
- local/setup.{sh,bash,zsh}
- local/_setup_util.py

Any idea on how I can stop those files from appearing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292010/remove-ros-artifact-from-cmake-install/) by [David Kristiansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/35401/david-kristiansen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-05-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To skip the generation / installation of these prefix level files you can pass `-DCATKIN_BUILD_BINARY_PACKAGE=1` to the CMake invocation.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Kristiansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/35401/david-kristiansen/) on 2018-05-23**:
This has bothered me for the good part of this day. This worked perfectly. Thank you. Is there some way of adding this to CMakeLists.txt?

I was a little fast there. I added SET(CATKIN_BUILD_BINARY_PACKAGE true) in my CMakeLists.txt. :)

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-05-23**:
I wouldn't recommend that. Basically when you build the package from source you want these files to be created (in order to setup the environment to use them). It is a packaging specific argument. I am not sure if you can define CPack specific CMake arguments in the CMake file.

**Comment by [David Kristiansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/35401/david-kristiansen/) on 2018-05-23**:
That is a very good point. I will have to look into that!

**Comment by [yaobin](https://answers.ros.org/users/56085/yaobin/) on 2020-12-01**:
Hi, where can I find the documentation of the macro "CATKIN_BUILD_BINARY_PACKAGE"? I tried to search in Google but didn't find any link.